# Cant boot OS from USB/DVD after deleting linux partition

Tags: grub2, windows, bootloader, grubrescue

After trying in google for almost 2 days I came here to post this.

I had Windows and linux in my hard disk. I tried to format linux but mistakenly deleted the partition. It got hung and forcefully restarted it. Then while system startup

> grub rescue

cmd prompt is coming.

I tried to use bootable USB with Windows and linux (one at a time) to repair/boot from it but getting stuck at initial stage itself and not going to the partition phase.

I googled and tried a lot no. of ways of how to use grub rescue to find the boot partition and boot but no solution. My initrd.img is missing for errorneously deleting the partition.

**What can I do right now? I just want to get inside, format and install any OS.**

Thanks in advance.

Edit : Solutions that are present in other sites includes using windows recovery cd or boot repair cd etc. but these things works only when your CD/USB gets booted in your PC, that is happening in my case. Whenever I try to use a bootable CD/USB to repair/format, but it is getting stuck in initial phase itself. It does not reach the screens where you get options.

Comment: If you cannot boot from a USB stick or CD/DVD, go into your BIOS setup and change the boot order. If the boot order lists the other device first and you are *sure* it is bootable but still it does not boot, this usually indicates a hardware problem.

Comment: @EliahKagan You are correct. I found that I have corrupted hard disk and bought a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to make a bootable image of your favourite OS , once booted use 'Try Ubuntu without installing' option and later on install it into your partition.

Comment: Tried. Got stuck after some memory check.